# Closing the browser should actually clear the session variables an ASP.net session id

Tags: asp.net, session

I have an ASP.net page. When I am closing the webpage I need to clear the session variables.

How to to handle this I need to maintain the timeout to 20 minutes.
If he closes and login for any number of times in the 20 minutes timed out time

Is there any possiblity for clearing the ASP.net session id

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283591/aspnet-session-destroy-if-he-closes-the-browser

Comment: Sorry, but I think you might be trying to solve the wrong problem here. Why do you need to clear session state immediately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[EDIT] As others have suggested, your session should time out eventually, but if you want to close the session before the timeout (for example to clean up large session objects) AND have javascript available to you...

You can do this with an `window.onbeforeunload` handler that posts back to a sign out page.

```
function CloseSession( )
{
    location.href = 'SignOut.aspx'; 
}
window.onbeforeunload = CloseSession;
```

You could also do it via AJAX.  The SignOut.aspx page (or whatever platform you are using) should abandon the user's session.

Comment: Just be prepared that in the event of the browser crashing this will not get called.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot do that.

1. You cannot rely on a event happening on the browser
2. There is no way the server can contact the browser to see if it is alive

You do not control the browser of the end-user. The user might close the browser, crash, disconnect from the Internet, have javascript disabled or crashed, etc, etc. Or the user might just enter another url (and after that the user might return to your page by using the back button, and expect to continue his/her session with your site).

The window.onbeforeunload is triggered with every unload of the page. Even if the user browses to another page on your site, so they might need your session again.

Answer (score 5):

I think the only good way to do this is by setting a timeout on the session variables on the server.  A web server has no way to know for sure whether a user has closed his browser or not.

Javascript is not a good option, since you can disable it client-side.

Comment: Not only that, but the browser may crash, the network connection may drop etc etc...

Answer (score 2):

What if the browser process ends?

[Here](http://www.webxpertz.net/forums/showthread.php?t=5236) is a trick

You should not have so many session variables that they require cleanup. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167873/repeated-cookie-query-or-storing-in-viewstate-which-is-the-better-practice#168050) post for other options.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically how ASP.Net implements its sessions, but part of the Cookie RFC is that session cookies (ones without a specific 'expires' date) are purged whenever the browser is closed.

Surely there's a way to get ASP.Net using proper session cookies rather than ones with a fixed timeout?

Answer (score -2):

Hello Try This javascript function

```
function ConfirmClose()  
{  
if (event.clientY < 0)  
{  
      /* Your asynchronouse request to the page and call that function*/ 
}  
}
/*now call this method on event of javascript*/
```

i didn'try this but it just came out from mind