# Javascript Deconstructor

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there any way that I can define a destructor for an object in JavaScript that will be called automatically when object is discarded?

Im creating my obj like so:

```
function SomeObject(){
    this.test = null;

    this.method = function(){
      alert("Testing Method");
    };

    this.destroy = function(){
      // Destroy stuff here
    };
}

var test = new SomeObject();
```

I can call destroy when needed but when the user exits the page I cant call destroy. The reason I need to do this is that I call functions in php using ajax that saves session data. I would like it to destroy the particular session data when im done with that particular js object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event

Comment: if you have a destroy() method, why don't you just call it when you're done with the object?

Comment: Einacio, I will but but if the user exits the page or changes pages within the application I cant call it. I will try the window.unload though.

Comment: No. There is no such thing as a "destructor" in JavaScript and using onunload/onbeforeunload is *not reliable* across browsers/situations (consider history navigation or refresh as simple counter-examples). Consider alternative approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a deconstructor for an object, but you can use `window.onbeforeunload` or `window.onunload` to do any last-moment adjustments.

If you return a string from `onbeforeunload` it will prompt the user that string as a `confirm` dialog as to whether they want to leave. This is useful primarily if you want to prompt the user to save their work or some similar state-preserving action.

Comment: Typically one should use `onbeforeunload` to prompt a user to save, and `onunload` when you *only* need to finish some state-preserving requests (settings cookies, localStorage, etc). I'm pretty certain `onbeforeunload` is supported by all modern browsers and IE7+ (test it and let me know).

Comment: @zzzzBov `onbeforeunload` is supported by all browsers (even IE6) except Opera.

Comment: @zzzzBov unfortunately it depends upon what causes the "unload" :(

Comment: YOUR WHOLE APP IS UNLOADED WHEN THE WINDOW IS UNLOADED.

Comment: @ResistDesign, I don't understand what point you're trying to make with that comment. Please consider using a civil tone and attempt to make an actual point. There are a variety of ways that page state can persist after a window is closed which it seems that you're not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

You can call that function on the `window.onunload` or [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287022/closing-the-browser-should-actually-clear-the-session-variables-an-asp-net-sessio) events. But be aware that this might be called even when the user navigates within your own application or when the back and forward buttons are used.

Comment: +1 Because this was the only answer to mention some caveats (although I think it's not exclusive).

Comment: That works well for me, I want it to be destroyed when they refresh or the back button is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to the unload event:

```
function SomeObject(){

    ...

    var that = this;
    $(window).unload(function() {
        that.destroy();
    });
}
```

This way your destroy method will be called when the user quits the page.

Without jQuery you can bind the event with this:

```
var event = 'load';
var handler = function() { ... };
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
}
```

Comment: For some values of "quits the page".

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution requires jQuery.