# ASP.NET - Sign out user on browser tab closed

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication, forms-authentication

i need to sign out an authenticated user in ASP.NET reliably when a browser tab gets closed. What is the recommended solution?

Thanks

Comment: (Duplicate) Take a look at this answer, it covers the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/287027/328968

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would do your sign-out logic when the session has ended.  But if you had to detect when page is closed, use this:

```
<body onunload="performMyLogoutLogic();">
...
...
</body>
```

Comment: This will also log the user out if they merely navigate away from the page, say, to a different page on the same site.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a generic handler to kill session and call this beforeunload like this:

```
function CloseSession( )
{
    location.href = 'KillSession.ashx?task=1'; 
}
window.onbeforeunload = CloseSession;
```

And in your KillSession.ashx do this

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
            {
                if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["task"].toString()))
                {
                 if(Request.QueryString["task"].toString()=="1")
                  {
                    Session["User"]==null;
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    context.Response.Write("Good Bye!");
                   }
                }
            }
```