# Storing a class object in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, storage

I have a class object which contains some data members and methods. I want to store this object for later use in the application.

Let me know which approach like session, cache etc is good in terms of performance.

```
Person per1 = new Person();
```

Here i want store the `per1` object for later use in the application

Comment: Have a look


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490864/difference-between-cache-and-session-in-real-time-for-asp-net

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653065/what-is-difference-between-session-cache-and-profile-in-asp-net

Comment: Application collects personal details of the users and stores them. In order to retrieve, each time calling database ...i want to keep them in some storage type  like session or cache or other approach. Want to which gives best performance in times. Hope it is clear

Comment: You need serialization, then save to file / DB.

Comment: Say If i want to access a method of Person class then i must deserialize the object first and get the required data, I think it takes some time. Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 2):

You use **`cache`** typically when you want to improve site performance: reduce database calls, accessing files on filesystem, calling external services, etc.

**`Session`** is used to store user-specific information that could be accessible from all web pages and will not be needed on next time user logs in.

Refer

[what is difference between session, cache and profile in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653065/what-is-difference-between-session-cache-and-profile-in-asp-net)

[Difference between cache and session in real time for Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490864/difference-between-cache-and-session-in-real-time-for-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

you can mark the object as serializable and store it and then deserialize it to load it again.

Serialization(you have to save it in any directory of your computer)

```
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(per1.GetType());
   StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Temporary\myfile.xml");
   serializer.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, per1);
```

Desirialization(load it from that directory)

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(per1.GetType());
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Temporary\myfile.xml");
object deserialized = serializer.Deserialize(reader.BaseStream);
city = (Person)deserialized;
```