# System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache information

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to ask if `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache` is per User like the `Sessions` or if it is per application. On which circumstances is nice to use Cache?.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[HttpContext.Cache Property - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx)

> There is **one instance of the Cache class per application domain**.
>   As a result, the Cache object that is returned by the Cache property
>   is the Cache object for all requests in the application domain.

For your question.

> On which circumstances is nice to use Cache?.

Keep that information in Cache which will be shared by multiple users and (usually) if its `readonly`. For example keeping lookup values in cache. You may see:

[Caching Data in an ASP.NET Web Pages Site for Better Performance](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/performance-and-traffic/15-caching-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-website)

Answer (score 2):

It's per `Application` and it's best to use when you have data that can be reused for multiple users/sessions.

For instance, a UserID will be stored in a `Session`. A User's language or name may also be stored in the `Session`.

But information useful to a group of Users or to all Users, has to be stored in the `Cache`.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428634/advantages-of-cache-vs-session) too.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one cache object `per key` value unlike `session` which is individual to user.
As it is a collection so you can have multiple cache variables.
There are different flavor of caching available in asp.net.
Here is a msdn link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The cache is global in the context of the application. It doesn't matter who stores items or who accesses them - just that they know how to do so. It's useful for persisting data that can be identical per user, for instance.